# Why does pthread_self() return the same id multiple times?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am trying to create a number of threads (representing persons), in a for loop, and display the person id, which is passed as an argument, together with the thread id. The person id is displayed as exepected, but the thread id is always the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* travelers(void* arg) {
    int* person_id = (int*) arg;
    printf("\nPerson %d was created, TID = %d", *person_id, pthread_self());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    pthread_t th[1000];

    for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        if ((pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, travelers, &i)) != 0) {
            perror("Could not create threads");
            exit(2);
        }
        else {
            // Join thread
            pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is something like this:

```
Person 0 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 1 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 2 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 3 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 4 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 5 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 6 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 7 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 8 was created, TID = 881035008
Person 9 was created, TID = 881035008
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since only one of the created threads runs at a time, every new one gets the same ID as the one that finished before, i.e. the IDs are simply reused. Try creating threads in a loop and then joining them in a second loop.

However, you will then have to take care that each thread independently reads the content of `i`, which will give you different headaches. I'd pass the index as context argument, and then cast it to an int inside the thread function.

Comment: If I join the threads in a separate loop, I get 10 different thread id's, but the person_id is always 0. What do you mean by passing the index as a context argument? Thanks!

Comment: You are passing the address (!!!) of `i` to each thread, so each thread will access the same variable. Instead of passing the address of a local variable, pass the value.

Comment: BTW: Stop using C-style casts, they are just a source of errors! In the case that you are passing a pointer, you can use a simple `static_cast` to convert back from `void*`, in the case that you want to pass an `int`, you need `reinterpret_cast` to convert to `void*` and back.

Answer (score 2):

It does that, because it re-uses thread-ids. The thread id is only unique among all running threads, but not for threads running at different times; look what your for-loop does essentially:

```
for (i = 0 to 10) {
  start a thread;
  wait for termination of the thread;
}
```

So the program has only one thread running at any given time, one thread is only started after the previous started thread has terminated (with pthread_join ()). To make them run at the same time, use two for loops:

```
for (i = 0 to 10) {
  start thread i;
}
for (i = 0 to 10) {
  wait until thread i is finished;
}
```

Then you will likely get different thread-ids. (I.e. you will get different thread-ids, but if the printf-function will write them out differently depends on your specific implementation/architecture, in particular if thread_t is essentially an int or not. It might be a long int, for example).

Comment: Interesting, seems I was the only one that voted up this answer, and that in spite of my own. Anyway, there is one small detail that could be clarified: Even if a thread stopped running long ago, you can't reuse the ID. Only after you called `pthread_join()` the thread is completely cleaned up and its ID up for reuse. This fine distinction is an important difference though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, travelers, &i)) != 0)
```

If the thread is successfully created it returns 0.  If `!= 0` will return false and you will execute the `pthread_join`.  You are effectively creating one thread repeatedly.